# Termite overlapping letters

Tags: arch-linux, termite

Im an user of Arch Linux and i'm using termite as my terminal emulator. It's a nice one but i having problem with it which is that is the overlapping of letters.The letters are not correctly oriented or spaced.Im using monospace as font and i tried to search for a solution but none of them helped. I'm posting my termite configuration file below:

```
[options]
scroll_on_output = false
scroll_on_keystroke = true
audible_bell = false
mouse_autohide = false
allow_bold = true
dynamic_title = true
urgent_on_bell = true
clickable_url = true
font = Monospace 15
scrollback_lines = 10000
search_wrap = true
#icon_name = terminal
geometry = 405x450
# "system", "on" or "off"
cursor_blink = system

# "block", "underline" or "ibeam"
cursor_shape = block

# $BROWSER is used by default if set, with xdg-open as a fallback
#browser = xdg-open

# set size hints for the window
#size_hints = false

# Hide links that are no longer valid in url select overlay mode
filter_unmatched_urls = true

# emit escape sequences for extra modified keys
#modify_other_keys = false

[colors]
#cursor = #dcdccc
#cursor_foreground = #dcdccc
foreground = #dcdccc
foreground_bold = #ffffff
#background = #3f3f3f

# 20% background transparency (requires a compositor)
background = rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.8)

# if unset, will reverse foreground and background
highlight = #2f2f2f

# colors from color0 to color254 can be set
color0 = #3f3f3f
color1 = #705050
color2 = #60b48a
color3 = #dfaf8f
color4 = #506070
color5 = #dc8cc3
color6 = #8cd0d3
color7 = #dcdccc
color8 = #709080
color9 = #dca3a3
color10 = #c3bf9f
color11 = #f0dfaf
color12 = #94bff3
color13 = #ec93d3
color14 = #93e0e3
color15 = #ffffff

[hints]
#font = Monospace 12
#foreground = #dcdccc
#background = #3f3f3f
#active_foreground = #e68080
#active_background = #3f3f3f
#padding = 2
#border = #3f3f3f
#border_width = 0.5
#roundness = 2.0

# vim: ft=dosini cms=#%s
```

any help would be appreciated i'm messing around this problem for 2 days now.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my font. I installed Source code pro font and it worked like charm.

```
pacman -S adobe-source-code-pro-fonts
```

and add

```
font = Source Code Pro for Powerline 11
```

in config file

Comment: The underlying problem was probably that the font you were using was broken or unsuitable for this purpose. Perhaps you could update this answer (or the question) to indicate which font was problematic.

Comment: In particular, that the `default` font available when you install ARCH from scratch, and LXDE from scratch is problematic in termite, and possibly elsewhere.